# When you download a picture from a web browser by pressing and holding then clicking download what folder does it get downloaded into?

Tags: ios

When you download a picture from a web browser by pressing and holding on the image then clicking download in the menu that pops up in which folder are you able to see it?

Is it the same on each browser (Safari, Chrome, etc), or does it differ?

EDIT: Referring to iOS

Answer (score 1):

The saved photos will show up in the [Photos app](https://www.apple.com/ios/photos/) on your device.

Comment: Which folder specifically will it go in?